# MetalLB cannot connect to Kubernetes API

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, flannel, internal-load-balancer, bare-metal-server

I installed MetalLB to be able to expose my services via an IP my network.
After the installation I tried a simple hello-world according:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/

I noticed, that the external IP is always in state

In the logs of the controller pod I got following error message:

```
{"caller":"reflector.go:205","level":"error","msg":"go.universe.tf/metallb/internal/k8s/k8s.go:231: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500\u0026resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout","ts":"2019-04-23T12:16:31.3694Z"}

{"caller":"reflector.go:205","level":"error","msg":"go.universe.tf/metallb/internal/k8s/k8s.go:237: Failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/metallb-system/configmaps?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dconfig\u0026limit=500\u0026resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout","ts":"2019-04-23T12:17:01.779341Z"}
```

I installed Kubernetes as usual and initialized with the following command:
 `sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.21.8.128/25 --apiserver-advertise-address=10.21.8.1`

In the `"kube-controller-manager.yaml"` I changed the size of the `"node-cidr-mask"` since the standard value is `"/24"` and my cluster size is `"/25"`:
`--node-cidr-mask-size=26`

I also installed flannel and Kubernetes Dashboard. Everything works fine!

I installed then MetalLB according:
https://metallb.universe.tf/tutorial/layer2/

And configured MetalLB with this config:

```
*apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: my-ip-space
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 10.21.8.129-10.21.8.254*
```

Did I missed something?

Comment: That looks like metallb can't talk to the apiserver, which version of kubernetes did you install?

Comment: Also, I just noticed: why are you using a range of IP addresses in MetalLB that's coming from the POD CIDR? MetalLB will work by intercepting ARP traffic for IPs on the same IP subnet that's used on an interface of one of the nodes itself.

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake with Flannel is to set your own pod-network-cidr with kubadm init and then not put the same CIDR in Flannel's YAML manifest where they hardcoded a default CIDR in the Flannel upstream file that may be different from yours.

Check that first.

Answer (score -2):

can you change the range , first try with limited range may be with single ip also you can try , i mean the addresses just mention - 10.21.8.12